# How to take a response from the server from WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, webkit

I'm trying to make authorization through Implicit Flow (https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user), the problem is that I don’t know how to get an access token from server after authorizing a user

```
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    logInWebView = WKWebView(frame: .null, configuration: config)
    logInWebView.uiDelegate = self
    logInWebView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = logInWebView
    let url = URL(string: "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=#######&display=mobile&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=audio&response_type=token")
    let req = URLRequest(url: url!)
    logInWebView.load(req)
```

Answer (score 0):

After successful authorization user browser is redirected to the redirect_uri, which contains your access token. It can be retrieved from there.

To achieve that

1. Subclass your VC with `WKNavigationDelegate`
2. Implement `didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation`
3. Get `webview.url` and split its URL components.
4. One of the components is your access token